# Why am I getting the error "integer number too large"? I'm including an "L" at the end

Tags: java, javac, long-integer

The following code is not compiling in Java:

java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.1) (suse-3.1-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)

```
public class XOR
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        long one = 595082963178094600000L;
    }
}
```

This throws the error:

```
XOR.java:5: integer number too large: 595082963178094600000
```

But I've properly indicated it as a long! The following also throws an error:

```
public class XOR
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        long one = new Long( "595082963178094600000" );
    }
}
```

This throws:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "595082963178094600000"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried the second one without quotes?

Comment: Are you sure that number isn't out of range of longs? If I recall the max long is ~9 quintillion which is smaller than your 595,082,963,178,094,600,000

Comment: This number looks so large! I hope you are counting money!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, maybe because it *is* `too large`?

```
595082963178094600000  //your value
  9223372036854775807  //Long.MAX_VALUE
```

You will need either `BigInteger` or `BigDecimal`:

```
new BigInteger("595082963178094600000")
```

Comment: Thanks. I was thrown off because the error did not say the long was too large, but the *integer* was too large.

Answer (score 2):

The values for a long must be be between -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 and 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 inclusive.  You cannot assign a value larger than these to a variable that's a long, even if you append an L to it, it will overflow the value and cause an error at compile time.